# Angular material : override css table inside a mat-menu

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm working on an application in Angular 7 and Angular Material cdk 6. It's my first time with Angular Material.
I have to override the css of my columns. None of my tries have worked.

*** HTML ***

```
<mat-menu #myMenu>
<ng-template myContentMenu>
    <table mat-table>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Date</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" >{{ item.date }}</td>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
</ng-template>
```

I don't know how to put padding, I've tried `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the .ts file and :

*** CSS ***

```
:host { /** With and without host */
   th.mat-column-date, td.mat-column-date {
      padding-left: 20px; /** With and without !important */
   }

   ::ng-deep mat-menu th.mat-column-date,
   ::ng-deep mat-menu td.mat-column-date {
     padding-left: 20px !important;
   }}
```

I don't know how to proceed. Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: would you mind creating a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: does it work when you add your css rules to your global css file?

Comment: @Arikael no, I'm not able to target the right tag. I'm very bad in CSS. Obviously, css inline in HTML works, but I would prefer to commit something less dirty :')

Comment: remove your `:host` declaration and add only our padding rules to your global style or to the style sheet which belongs to the component containing your table.

Like -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqd4qz
The symbol column has a padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just add your own class to the desired element. For example, I have added "col-padding" class to the th element.

#### HTML

`<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="col-padding">Date</th>`

#### CSS

```
.col-padding {
    padding-left: 20px; 
}
```